# UIRefreshControlの表示がおかしい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

### 前提

UIRefreshControlを用いて、画面を引っ張って更新する機能を追加しようと試みています。
2層に重ねたContainerViewに接続した、2つのTableViewControllerのクラス内にて、UIRefreshControlの設定を行なっています。

#### 発生している問題

UIRefreshControlに関しては同じコードを記載しているのにも関わらず、
インジケータの表示位置が ⑴NavigationBar内 であったり、⑵TableViewControlerの裏? の２つのパターンに分かれて表示されてしまいます。
[image: IssueImage]

#### 該当のソースコード

```
class TableViewController1: UITableViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

---

```
class TableViewController2: UITableViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

#### 動作環境

- Xcode 10.1
- Swift 4

どなたか解決策やアドバイスをいただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Try `tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()` instead of `refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContainerViewの下に、ダミーのUIScrollViewを挿入することで解決いたしました。
ご迷惑をおかけいたしました。